# Form error for duplicate entry in doctrine

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I want to add manual form error for the duplicate entry in the database. Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user (google_id,
>   facebook_id, alias, token, email_verify_token, email, mobile,
>   password, salt, last_login, created, updated, is_active,
>   tax_exclusive, tax, delete_account, delete_seller_account,
>   deactivite_account, created_by, updated_by, currency) VALUES (?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params
>   [null, null, null, null, null, "nirajan.panthee@gmail.com", null,
>   "ffb34b831264f833d343944198c91fea", null, null, "2016-12-12 16:59:50",
>   "2016-12-12 16:59:50", 1, null, null, 0, 0, 0, null, null, null]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'nirajan.panthee@gmail.com' for key 'UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74'

Currently, I am handling form error like below.

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      {{ form_widget(form.email,{'attr':{'class':'form-row'}}) }}
      {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
 </div>
```

Comment: add the`UniqueEntity` constraints

Comment: I do not know your underlying form, but maybe the [UniqueEntity constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) could help.